# Couldn't find Plan with id=monthly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am following Railscast #288 in setting up Stripe's subscription with my rails app. When I type in /subscriptions/new?plan_id=monthly I am receiving a

> `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error Couldn't find Plan with id=monthly.`

I followed everything with the exception of adding files to the application.html.erb. I can't find that information in the stripe documents so I am assuming that part of the tutorial is outdated (plus that would have nothing to do with my current error).

Controller:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @plans = Plan.order("price")
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :subscriptions
  resources :plans
```

Model:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
end
```

Model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :plan
    validates_presence_of :plan_id
    validates_presence_of :email

    attr_accessor :stripe_card_token

    def save_with_payment
      if valid?
        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
        self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
        save!
      end
    rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
      logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
      errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
      false
    end
  end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Signing up for "<%= @subscription.plan.name %>"</h1>
<p>Includes <strong><%= @subscription.plan.length %> Subscription</strong> for only <strong><%= number_to_currency @subscription.plan.price %></strong> per month!</p>

<%= form_for @subscription do |f| %>
  <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <% if @subscription.stripe_card_token.present? %>
    Credit card has been provided.
  <% else %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
      <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
      <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div id="stripe_error">
    <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb:

```
  create_table "subscriptions", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "plan_id"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "stripe_customer_token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "plans", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "price",      precision: 10, scale: 0
    t.integer  "length"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query string, you are passing `monthly` value as `plan_id` (which should be id). If you want to pass plan name, you can change you query to look like that: `/subscriptions/new?plan=monthly`

and change your controller to look like that:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    plan = Plan.find_by!(name: params[:plan])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
  end
...
```

Comment: I used a id previously such as /new?plan_id=1 and it gives same error `Couldn't find Plan with id=1`

Comment: Maybe you don't have plan with id = 1 in your database?

Answer (score 1):

I believe plan_id should be an integer and not 'monthly' so it should be the id corresponding to the plan

You will also need to add the line for the js file to the application.html.erb file unless you use the gem.

You should look at the stripe docs to see the changes.

I believe the railscast is a little outdated.

Comment: Thanks will take a deeper look into docs. I had to add the plan id information to the Plans table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find the record via `id` using `find` method and your `params[:plan_id]` looks like `name` column. You have 2 options:

- Send plan id:

  `?plan_id=1`
- Change the way you load the plan instance:

  `Plan.find_by!(name: 'monthly')`

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot to add the plan information to the Plan table first. It works now as id=1.